# AudioToolBox doesn't play on some devices

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, audio, audiotoolbox

I have two applications that use the audiotoolbox framework to play short mp3 files.
The deployment target is: 4.0
And the Base SDK is: iOS 5.0 SDK

I have an iphone 4 with iOS 5.0 and an iPhone 3GS with iOS 5.0. Both of them are playing the sounds. A friend of mine that have iPad with iOS 4.3, can't play any of the sounds. And another friend with iPhone 4 with iOS 4.2 can't play the sounds as well. It looks like its something with the iOS but I don't really have any clue what is the real reason for it not to play.

Here is an example of my code for playing a file:

**H. file (only relevant code):**

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h> 

SystemSoundID soundID1;
```

**M. file (only relevant code):**

```
@synthesize soundID1

- (IBAction)one:(id)sender
{    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path], &soundID1);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID1);
}

- (void)dealloc { AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID (self.soundID1);}
```

Comment: Edit: I'm a newbie so forgive me if I did some crazy mistakes. Also I'm not sure 100% that I used the audiotoolbox here... but still looking for solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use AVAudioPlayer toplay a sound file.

Here is the Code.

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"mp3"];
    1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path1] error:NULL];
    1.delegate = self;
    [1 setVolume:1.0];
    [1 prepareToPlay];

}

- (IBAction)one:(id)sender
{

    if (1 && 1.playing) {
        [1 stop];
        [1 setCurrentTime:0];
        [1 play];
    }else {
        [1 play];
    }

}
```

since iOS 5 using ARC, it doesn't need to release. But, if you use older iOS, then create a release on dealloc method.